# Covariant function parameter in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance

I want to implement a function that optionally takes an Activity class and redirects to it. If no class is provided, a default will be used.

In Java I'd do

```
public void onComplete(@Nullable Class<? extends Activity> redirectTarget) {
    if (redirectTarget == null) redirectTarget = DefaultActivity.class;
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context, new Intent(context, redirectTarget), null);
}
```

Now, I tried the following in Kotlin:

```
fun <T : Activity> onComplete(redirectTarget: Class<in T> = DefaultActivity::class.java) {
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context, Intent(context, redirectTarget), null)
}
```

I thought `in T` would accept any subclasses of T in the parameter but in the above example, I get a warning saying

```
Type missmatch. 
Expected: Class <in T>
Found: Class<DefaultActivity>
```

How do I implement a function that accepts any Activity class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with variance. This is an issue with how you're trying to use generics.

Let's say you have a function:

```
fun <T> print(toPrint: T) = println(toPrint.toString())
```

You can call this function like this:

```
print<Int>(1)
```

All is good.

But let's say you want to have a default `String` parameter when the user doesn't want to specify the `toPrint' argument. Following your approach, you would do:

```
fun <T> print(toPrint: T = "") = println(toPrint.toString())
```

In a world where this is legal, what would then happen if you call the function specifying the type but not the argument? E.g.:

```
print<Int>()
```

The type of the default parameter doesn't match the type at the call site.

So how to go about solving your issue?
It turns out you don't even need a generic function, as you could do:

```
fun onComplete(redirectTarget: Class<out Activity> = DefaultActivity::class.java) {
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context, Intent(context, redirectTarget), null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't now why this is like this but you just need to cast it to `Class<T>`. change your function to this.

```
fun <T : Activity> onComplete(redirectTarget: Class<in T> = DefaultActivity::class.java as Class<T>) {
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context, Intent(context, redirectTarget), null)
}
```

i just add `as Class<T>` at the end of `onComplete` inputs

## Update:

you also can write extention function

```
fun Class<out Activity>?.onComplete() {
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context, Intent(context, this ?: DefaultActivity::class.java), null)
}
```

and you can use it like this

```
MainActivity::class.java.onComplete()
```

and for default class

```
null.onComplete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
fun onComplete(redirectTarget:Class<out Activity> = DefaultActivity::class.java){
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context, Intent(context, redirectTarget), null)
}
```